# "Invalid command." when using basic unix command in CYGWIN

Tags: unix, cygwin

I just installed cygwin on a new laptop and all basics command such as, cksum, ls, head etc.. it says "command invalid". Did I miss something during the installation?

Here are some examples :

```
sftp> vi somefile.txt
Invalid command.

sftp> head somefile.txt
Invalid command.
```

Please point me out which package I should install to have all basic text command.

Comment: The prompt reads "sftp", which suggests to me that you might be running a program, and that program is failing to understand the commands.  If you launch a new Cygwin window, do you see the same thing?  If you type "exit" at the prompt above, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running sftp and getting error messages from its command prompt. This suggests you may be trying to connect from a remote host, or somehow got to a sftp prompt. In any case, entering "exit" or "quit" should get you out of sftp.

When you finish installing cygwin using the recommended setup command, you should have an icon on your desktop, and a start menu shortcut (which may not be visible under Win10). Using the icon or shortcut will start the mintty terminal emulator and a bash login shell. There you will be be able to run basic unix commands. You may need to install additional packages for less common commands. For instance, to use the C/C++ compiler, you will need to install several packages.

The documentation on the cygwin web site explains this in great detail. If you spend an hour or two reading the site you will have a much better understanding of how to use cygwin successfully.